# Isomorphism between two cubic curves takes their infinity points to one another

Tags: geometry, elliptic-curves

I am working on a chapter about the plane cubics from Basic Algebraic Geometry written Shafarevich.

One of exercises asks following question.

> Suppose that two cubics $X_1,X_2$ with equations $y^2=x^3+a_i x+b_i$ for  $i=1,2$ are isomorphic. Prove that an isomorphism between $X_1$ and $X_2$ takes their points at infinity to one another is given by a linear map.

I guess the condition involving points at infinity provides that the isomorphism is actually a group isomorphism, when we consider $X_1,X_2$ as groups having their points of infinity as identities.

However, I could not proceed to prove that the isomorphism is given by a linear map.

Thank you for reading and please give any hint to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick answer using Riemann-Roch. Let $\varphi=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ be such an isomorphism. Since $x$ has a pole of order 2 at infinity, $\varphi$ has to map it to a function with a pole of order 2 at infinity. The space of such functions has dimension 2 by Riemann-Roch, so it is generated by $x$ and $1$. This shows that $f(x,y)=\alpha x +\beta$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in K$ (with $\alpha\neq 0$). Analogously, $y$ has a pole of order 3 at infinity and the space of functions with a pole of order at most 3 at infinity is generated by $1,x,y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your explanation. But what I wonder is that Duality and Riemann-Roch is not yet introduced in this section. So the author might have expected readers to prove this problem by not using those theorems. Can we have more elementary proof only using group structures of elliptic curves?